# Surjective homomorfism between $M/M_1$ to $M/M_2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions, modules, free-modules

I have a module $M$ and $M_1$, $M_2$ submodules of $M$ such that $M_1\le M_2$. I have to proof that the mapping $f: M/M_1\to M/M_2$ given by $f(\overline{m})=\overline{m}$ is a surjective homomorfism. I just wanted to know if my proof is correct.

First, to show that $f$ is an homomorfism let $\overline{x},\overline{y}\in M/M_1$. So,

\begin{align*}
    f(\overline{x}+\overline{y})=f(\overline{x+y})
    =\overline{x+y}
    =\overline{x}+\overline{y}
    =f(\overline{x})+f(\overline{y}).
\end{align*}

And if $a\in R$ and $\overline{x}\in M/M_1$, then
\begin{align*}
    f(a\overline{x})=f(\overline{ax})
    =\overline{ax}
    =a\overline{x}
    =af(\overline{x}).
\end{align*}

Now for the surjective, let $y\in M/M_2$ then exists $m\in M$ such that $y=m+M_2$. Let $x=m+M_1$. Then, $x\in M/M_1$ and $f(x)=f(m+M_1)=f(\overline{m})=\overline{m}=m+M_2$. Is that right?

Comment: How do you know the map is well defined?

Comment: Oh, that's because $M_1\le M_2$

Comment: How does it follow from that?

Comment: Okeeey, i'll try again :( But the rest of the proof is correct? :(

Comment: It’s fine, but I wouldn’t use the $\overline{m}$ notation. Writ $m+M_1$ and $m+M_2$.

Comment: Okey, thank youuuu